# Error: Route generator for 'item' was not included in parameters passed. (Typescript, angular2, javascript, html)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

Screenshot of error: 
http://imgur.com/eHiNEYi

Link to full project:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/84svnggv8xeub5m/FullProjectEbayClone.zip?dl=0

Context of problem:

The website is like a clone of ebay but uses a search bar that takes data from wikipedia.

I'm trying to make a button that will:

1. Save the variable "item" or "item.name" (I'm trying to get the name of the of the search result of whatever the user typed in by clicking the button called "Click here to bid on this item".)
2. Transfer the user to the bidding page for that specific item.

Code of the button in html (wiki.component.ts):

```
 <button (click)="gotoItem(item)">Click here to bid on this item.</button>
```

Code of the function "gotoItem(item)" (wiki.component.ts):

```
 gotoItem (item: any) {
    this.router.navigate(['BiddingPage', {item}]);
  }
```

Links to plunker and more details about this problem:

stackoverflow.com/questions/37422205/displaying-data-that-is-consistent-with-search-results-on-a-different-webpage-t

Full code of wiki.component.ts

```
import { Component }        from 'angular2/core';
import { JSONP_PROVIDERS }  from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable }       from 'rxjs';
import { WikipediaService } from './wikipedia.service';
import {Router, RouteParams, RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'Wikithing',
  template: `
    <h1>Search and Display Page</h1>
    <p><i>Fetches after each keystroke</i></p>
    <input #term (keyup)="search(term.value)"/>
    <ul>
     <li *ngFor="#item of items | async">{{item}} <br> <p> 

     </p> Price (in USD): $ {{item.price}} <br> <p>

      </p> Availability: 24 hours <br> <p> 

      </p> Quantity currently in stock: {{quantity}}

       <br> <p> 

      </p> Image of item: <img src="http://weknowyourdreamz.com/images/apple/apple-05.jpg" alt="Apple" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
       <br> <p> 
       </p>
               <p>

            </p>

             <a [routerLink]="['BiddingPage']">Click here to bid on this item.</a>
           <button (click)="gotoItem(item)">Click here to bid on this item.</button>
            <p>

                </p>
        <br> <p> 
       </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  providers:[JSONP_PROVIDERS, WikipediaService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink],

})
export class WikiComponent {
  constructor (private wikipediaService: WikipediaService, private router:Router) {}
  items: Observable<string[]>;
  //  item: Item[] = [];



  search (term: string) {
    this.items = this.wikipediaService.search(term);
    this.items.map((items) => items.map(() => ({
      name: items,
      prices: Math.random(),
      quantity: Math.random(),
      availability: Math.random()
    })));

    var Prices = Math.random() + Math.random();
    var quantity = Math.random();
  }
  gotoItem (item: any) {
    this.router.navigate(['BiddingPage', {item}]);
  }
}
```

Full code of biddingpage.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';
import {Observable} from'rxjs/Rx'
import { WikipediaService } from './wikipedia.service';
import { Jsonp, URLSearchParams } from 'angular2/http';
import { Input } from 'angular2/core';
import { JSONP_PROVIDERS }  from 'angular2/http';
import { Subject }          from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Component({
  selector: 'BiddingPageComponent',
  templateUrl: 'app/BiddingPage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/BiddingPage.component.css'],
  providers: [HeroService, JSONP_PROVIDERS, WikipediaService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]

})



export class BiddingPageComponent{
    constructor (private wikipediaService: WikipediaService) {}
      @Input() item : any;
myFunction(slotvalue) 
 {
        this.slot1 = slotvalue;
        this.numberofbids +=1;
         alert("You have entered a new bid.");
 }
  numberofbids = 0;
    slot1 = 0;
  secondsLeft = 0;
  hoursLeft = 0;
  mightbehours = 0;
  ticks = 0;

  items : any;
  ngOnInit(ticks, secondsLeft, hoursLeft, hoursLeft2){
    let timer = Observable.timer(2000,1000);
    let HoursOrMinutesTimer = Observable.timer(2000, 1000);
    let HoursLeftTimer = Observable.timer(2000, 1000);
    timer.subscribe(t=>this.ticks = t);
    secondsLeft = 100;
    timer.subscribe(t=>this.secondsLeft = -t + 86400);
    HoursOrMinutesTimer.subscribe(t=>this.hoursLeft = t/60);
    HoursLeftTimer.subscribe(t=>this.mightbehours = t/3600);
     //this.routeParams.get('item');



  }

  //items: Observable<string[]>;
  //  item: Item[] = [];



  search (term: string) {
     this.items = this.wikipediaService.search(term);
    this.items.map((items) => items.map(() => ({
      name: items,
      prices: Math.random(),
      quantity: Math.random(),
      availability: Math.random()
    })));

    var Prices = Math.random() + Math.random();
    var quantity = Math.random();




}


    //this.wikipediaService.getHero(item)
   //   .then(item => this.hero = item);


}
```

Full code of biddingpage.component.html

```
<html>
    <center>
<h3>Bidding Page</h3>
<a name="top"></a>
</center>
<p>



 </p>




        <p>



          </p>


  <form>
        <img src="http://weknowyourdreamz.com/images/apple/apple-05.jpg" alt="Apple" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
        <p>
            </p>
        <label for="name">Name of item: {{item.name}} </label>
        <p>



          </p>
        <label for="name">Original Price: {{item.price}} </label>
         <p>



          </p>
           <p>



          </p>
        <label for="name">Number of items in stock: {{item.quantity}} </label>



         <p>
          </p>
        Description of item’s current condition:
         <p>



          </p>
                <label for="name">Description of item’s current condition: </label>
                <label for="name">The apple is a fleshy fruit from the apple tree. 
                    It is in the species Malus domestica in the rose family Rosaceae. 
                    The apple is one of the most grown tree fruits. It is grown in orchards.</label>
        <p>



            </p>
        <label for="name">Time elapsed (in seconds): {{ticks}} </label>


          <p>



          </p>


          <p>
          <label for="name">Time elapsed (in minutes): {{hoursLeft}} </label>


          </p>
          <p>

            </p>
          <p>
          <label for="name">Time elapsed (in hours): {{mightbehours}} </label>


          </p>
        <label for="name">Current highest bid: $ {{slot1}} </label>

        <p>




          </p>

 <p>
             <label for="name">Time left (in hours): {{secondsLeft/3600}} </label>
             <p>

          <p>
             <p>
             <label for="name">Time left (in minutes): {{secondsLeft/60}} </label>
             <p>

          <p>
             <label for="name">Time left (in seconds): {{secondsLeft}} </label>
             <p>

             NOTE: There are 86400 seconds in one day.



          </p>
           <label for="name">Number of bids so far: {{numberofbids}} </label>



          <p>



          </p>


  Bid slot 1: <p>$ {{slot1}} </p>
          <p>



          </p>


<label for="name">Enter your bid: </label>
<input type="number" #bid class="form-control" required>

<button (click)='myFunction(bid.value)'>Click here to bid.</button>



          <p>







          </p>









<!-- 
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question. Links to external resources might be helpful but a question needs to contain the relevant parts directly.  You can't expect anyone to download some arbitrary archive files locally. You can make a minmal example that allows to reproduce for example in a Plunker. You can't expect someone to investigate your full project.

Comment: here is the plunker but I don't think I could reproduce the error without all the files because the routes cause the issue even though it only exists in the wiki.component.ts and/or biddingpage.component.ts
https://plnkr.co/edit/1lcI4dURHwA8D9IQtqSf?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{item}` in

```
this.router.navigate(['BiddingPage', {item}]);
```

is invalid. You can pass an array that contains strings or objects. `{item}` is neither.

You might want to pass

```
this.router.navigate(['BiddingPage', {item: item}]);
```

or in the new RC.1 router

```
this.router.navigate(['BiddingPage/' + item]);
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot but now I get this error but I will post a different question here is the screenshot anyways though thank you again http://imgur.com/GvLdwBC